# How can i get the hidden field value inside a listview item template using javascript of jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net

html source :

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstviewclients" runat="server" onitemcommand="lstviewclients_ItemCommand">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <img ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></img>                        


    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
   <%--  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("schoolid") %>' class="valoflst" Visible="false"></asp:Label>--%>
    <img class="div-shadow" ID="img" runat="server" src='<%#Eval("logo") %>' 
        title='<%#Eval("schoolname") %>'  AlternateText='<%#Eval("schoolname") %>' alt='<%#Eval("schoolname") %>' onclick="ImageClick();" />

        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfschoolid"  Value='<%#Eval("schoolid") %>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

and i am using script like this

```
function ImageClick( )
{
    var hv = $('#hfschoolid').val();
    alert(hv);
}
```

but i m not able to get the value of the hidden field!

Comment: Your "HTML" contains a lot of ASP. Could you post the code as the browser receives it as this is a client-side problem? Copy-paste it from `view-source`.

Comment: Search SO for clientID or FindControl

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if jquery can find asp:HiddenField, I suggest that you use asp:label instead of asp:HiddenField and give it style display:none. At least I am sure that Jquery can find the label.

I also suggest that you pass the label by ClientID

Answer (score 0):

this is because asp render controls id with prefix. in jquery you can find an element by matching the id from end. like below

`var hv = $('[id$="hfschoolid"]').val();`

try above change and let me know whether it's working...